Why do I get a read timeout after every 100 values sent from Arduino to Firebase?
I'm trying to send the value read by an encoder to a Firebase database. However, after 100 sends its function firebaseData.errorReason() give a read timeout error. Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance! Cheers
//libraries
#include "Firebase_Arduino_WiFiNINA.h"    //DataBase
#include <SPI.h>                          //Encoder

//pins
#define BUZZER_PIN 2                      //Peripherals
#define AMT22_NOP 0x00                    //Encoder
#define AMT22_RESET 0x60                  //Encoder
#define AMT22_ZERO 0x70                   //Encoder
#define RES12 12                          //Encoder
#define RES14 14                          //Encoder
#define ENC_0 2                           //Encoder
#define SPI_MOSI MOSI                     //Encoder
#define SPI_MISO MISO                     //Encoder
#define SPI_SCLK SCK                      //Encoder

//wifi                                    //DataBase
//NetCasa
//#define WIFI_SSID "MXXXXX"
//#define WIFI_PASSWORD "CXXXXX6"
//NetTelemovel
#define WIFI_SSID "OXXXXXXs"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "nXXXX"

//Firebase                                //DataBase
#define FIREBASE_HOST "XXXXXXX-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "tJpdUJr2cwGoI49WtLXX76E43gqlwUSyCiELfLHl"

//Define Firebase data object
FirebaseData firebaseData;
String ComplitPath = "/Exercise2/angle";  //Path da Base de Dados. 1-Simular a andar

//variaveis auxiliares
int j = 0;
int i = 0;

uint16_t encoderPosition;                //Encoder
float encoderPositionDegree;             //Encoder
uint8_t attempts;                        //Encoder

void setup() {
  //Peripherals
  pinMode(BUZZER_PIN, OUTPUT);
  //Encoder
  pinMode(SPI_SCLK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SPI_MOSI, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SPI_MISO, INPUT);
  pinMode(ENC_0, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  //Encoder
  digitalWrite(ENC_0, HIGH);
  SPI.begin();

  //Conecting to WIFI
  Serial.println("----------");
  Serial.print("Conectando ao Wi-Fi");
  int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    status = WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("----------");
  //Connection to Firebase
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH, WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);  //Let's say that if the connection is down, try to reconnect automatically

  if (!Firebase.beginStream(firebaseData, "/test/data")) {
    //Could not begin stream connection, then print out the error detail
    Serial.println(firebaseData.errorReason());
  }
  
}

void loop() {

  readEncoderValues();

  float n = encoderPositionDegree;
  n=round(n * 100) / 100;
  n=ProcessedEncoderValues(n);
  if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, ComplitPath, n)) {
    if (firebaseData.dataType() == "float")      // se hace para asegurar que si el tipo almacenado es entero cogemso el valor correctamente y no basura
      Serial.println(firebaseData.floatData());  //Realmente estamos leyendo con esto el valor introducido
    i = i + 1;

  } else {
    Serial.println("ERROR : " + firebaseData.errorReason());
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.println();
    i = 0;
  }
  
  delay(250);
}

float ProcessedEncoderValues(float i) {
  if(i>180){
    return i-360;
  }
  else 
    return i;
}

I've tried to create a new field to every value sent, but the error is still the same every 100 values sent.
void loop() {

  /*
  Serial.println("Bom");
  PlaySound(GoodSound, GoodSoundNoteDurations, SizeGood); // Tocar o som "Bom!"
  delay(500); // Esperar 1 segundo
  */

  /*
  Serial.println("Mau");
  PlaySound(BadSound, BadSoundNoteDurations, SizeBad); // Tocar o som "Mau!"
  delay(500); // Esperar 1 segundo
  */

  if (j == 0) {

    /* testar */

    String ComplitPath1 = path1 + "/Value" + String(i);

    // Adiciona zeros à esquerda se o número tiver apenas um dígito
    if (i < 100000000) {
      ComplitPath1 = path1 + "/Value" + String(i, DEC);
    }

    if (i < 10000000) {
      ComplitPath1 = path1 + "/Value0" + String(i, DEC);
    }

    if (i < 1000000) {
      ComplitPath1 = path1 + "/Value00" + String(i, DEC);
    }

    if (i < 100000) {
      ComplitPath1 = path1 + "/Value000" + String(i, DEC);
    }

    if (i < 10000) {
      ComplitPath1 = path1 + "/Value0000" + String(i, DEC);
    }

    if (i < 1000) {
      ComplitPath1 = path1 + "/Value00000" + String(i, DEC);
    }

    if (i < 100) {
      ComplitPath1 = path1 + "/Value000000" + String(i, DEC);
    }

    if (i < 10) {
      ComplitPath1 = path1 + "/Value0000000" + String(i, DEC);
    }

    readEncoderValues();

    float n = encoderPositionDegree;
    n = round(n * 100) / 100;
    n = ProcessedEncoderValues(n);
    if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, ComplitPath1, n)) {
      if (firebaseData.dataType() == "float")      // se hace para asegurar que si el tipo almacenado es entero cogemso el valor correctamente y no basura
        Serial.println(firebaseData.floatData());  //Realmente estamos leyendo con esto el valor introducido
      i = i + 1;

    } else {
      Serial.println("ERROR : " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.println();
      //i = 0;
    }
  }

  if (i > 110) {
    j = 1;
  }

  delay(50);
}

